# Correct colour display of Default.png on iPhone

Tags: iphone, splash-screen, default.png

I'm using the Default.png method to create a splashscreen. I'm using the same file for my background and the Default.png (except default.png has the 20 pixel status bar at the top).

However, the iphone isn't displaying them in them the same. The Default.png is being displayed darker than the background, so it's painfully obvious when the app is loaded.

As a visual example of what I mean, please see below:

[image: Splashscreen is left, loaded screen is right]

The image on left is the Default.png whereas the image on the right is when the app has loaded. The difference looks subtle here but when the whole image changes, it looks quite drastic.

Is this an issue with the colour-formatting of the pngs? Or is this an iOS feature whereby the Default.png appears slightly darker anyway?

It's probably not worth mentioning but I'm using Monotouch to develop my app, I doubt that would have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. The designer sent me new versions of the backgrounds and the Default.png is now displaying the correct colour.

I have a feeling I had saved the previous version with a different colour profile to the background, hence why it was being displayed differently.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem like this after editing a screenshot with OSX's Preview to cut out the status bar (as needed for iPad splashes). Preview sticked a color profile, and splash screen appears darker than the real thing in device.

If you open the image with GIMP, it shows a dialog offering to convert the color profile to SRGB. Take it (press "Convert") and save the image. This fixes the color difference.

Comment: It would be better to flag this answer as correct, since it is more helpful than the recent flagged one.